# Regex expression not behaving as expected in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

In matlab I have a string like :

```
y = '[3-G]]3|25+3|[3-G]4|25+4|G5|25+5|F'
```

Then I have a variable named intHit, which I need to return a cell array, containing an int if it is followed by a sign. So if we define it as:

```
intHit = regexp(y,'(\d*)([+-])','Match');
```

It returns something like:

```
intHit =
```

1×5 cell array

```
'3-'    '25+'    '3-'    '25+'    '25+'
```

HOWEVER, sometimes my intHit call, depending on the input of y returns minus(-) signs without an integer in front of it. I think my regex expression is faulty. Can someone help me format this so it will only return an integer followed by a plus(+) or minus(-) sign. So always something like the example above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
intHit = regexp(y,'(\d+)([+-])','Match');
                      ^--- that's the change
```

I think you had the wrong [quantifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-43073). `*` will match 0 or more times consecutively (which means it could match lone pluses and minuses), while `+` will match 1 or more times consecutively.

Also, if you're not capturing tokens, you can simplify your match expression to just `'\d+[+-]'`.